# XamarinAndroidBuildResourceRestore Error when Build after update xamarin nuget

Tags: c#, xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.android, targets

I have this error after updated Xamarin.forms 2.3.5.235-pre2, I Hit it when building the App.Droid project. It says "XamarinBuildAndroidResourceRestore could not be initialized" and "XamarinBuildAndroidResourceRestore target not support the "VSInstallRoot" parameter".

[image: Error Description]

I have the following config:

```
Xamarin VS v4.4.0.34
Xamarin.Android SDK v7.2.0.7
Visual Studio 2017
```

And the following Build output:

```
1>  App.Droid -> D:\project\App.Droid\App.Droid\bin\Release\App.Droid.dll
2>------ Début de la génération : Projet : App.Droid, Configuration : Release Any CPU ------
2>D:\project\App.Droid\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(243,5): warning : All projects referencing App.Droid.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317569.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3243: Impossible de résoudre le conflit entre "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" et "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choix arbitraire de "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3277: Des conflits entre différentes versions du même assembly dépendant ont été détectés, mais n'ont pas pu être résolus.  Ces conflits de référence sont consignés dans le fichier journal de génération quand le niveau de commentaires est défini sur Detailed.
2>D:\project\Creonslelien\Creonslelien.Shared\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.3\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(98,4): error MSB4064: Le paramètre "VsInstallRoot" n'est pas pris en charge par la tâche "XamarinBuildAndroidResourceRestore". Vérifiez que le paramètre existe pour la tâche et qu'il représente une propriété d'instance publique définissable.
2>D:\project\Creonslelien\Creonslelien.Shared\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.3\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(92,3): error MSB4063: Impossible d'initialiser la tâche "XamarinBuildAndroidResourceRestore" avec ses paramètres d'entrée. 
========== Génération : 1 a réussi, 1 a échoué, 4 mis à jour, 0 a été ignoré ==========
========== Déploiement : 0 a réussi, 0 a échoué, 0 a été ignoré ==========
```

Please Help, and thank you for all your responses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to update Xamarin.Build.Download package to 0.4.5 version. With version 0.4.3 I see the same error

Answer (score 2):

I found that cleaning the project and restarting VS2017 resolved it for me.  It occurred when I changed a few DLLs that were binding libraries I wrote that I changed but VS was unable to update them without shutting down and restarting the app.

Hope this helps someone.